# Why can't I switch directly to B2C tenant directory from the top right of the Azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am sure there's a super simple answer to this: I created a mobile app a couple of years back and had to create a tenant directory to sit on top of my main directory. As far as I can remember the B2C tenant sat in the tenant directory and where I registered the app. When I wanted to access the tenant directory, I just went to the top right hand corner of the screen, clicked on my username and a dropdown appeared that said "switch directory". Clicked on that and switched to the tenant directory.

The tenant directory is still there now from a couple of years ago, so I can switch into that if I wanted to.

I am now building another app, so created a B2C tenant which automatically created ANOTHER tenant directory.

If I now go into the top right hand corner, I can still only see two directories... the main directory and the really old tenant for the previous app. The new tenant directory created last week is not there.

If I want to go into the new tenant directory created last week, I have to go into the main directory, click into the resource group, click on the B2C tenant and then click on "open B2C tenant" which takes me to the B2C tenant directory.

Why can't I access this from the top right as before?

Comment: I'm guessing you are looking at the 'all directories' tab and not the 'favourites' tab?

Comment: Well not noticing the "all directories" tab, would be incredibly stupid. And as it turns out, I did not notice the "all directories" tab. Thanks @bolt-io :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I agree with ***@bolt-io***, to switch to Azure AD B2C directory, you need to check all directories tab.

To switch the directory, ***Go to Azure Portal ->  Click on settings -> Directories + subscriptions -> All Directories***

[image]

The **Favorites tab** only displays the directory which is marked as favorite not all directories:

[image]

- Make sure to have required permissions to switch the directory.
- Make sure you have logged in with correct account.
- If still the issue persists, try clearing your browser cache and cookies, and then logging in to the Azure portal again.